# How to customize the bottom navigation in react native

Tags: react-native

trying to build the bottom navigation in react native like the below image any help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIPo0.png)

Comment: what ui library are you using?

Comment: react-navigation v5

Comment: I meant UI library not navigation lib. Are you using a UI library? Or just styling with css

Comment: no no not using any UI library. just trying to fix it with styling.

Comment: Great, can you please paste some code so I can help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `react-native-router-flux` or anything else and switch case with your style like bottom:

first `import { Router, Scene ,Drawer} from 'react-native-router-flux';`

in your default export app component :

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
              <Scene key="splash" component={Splash} initial/>
              <Scene key="main" tabs={true} swipeEnabled={false} tabBarPosition={'bottom'}
                    tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} showLabel={false} default="home">
                  <Scene
                      key="home"
                      title="Home"
                      icon={TabIcon}
                      hideNavBar={true}
                      initial
                      component={Home}/>
                  <Scene
                      key="categories"
                      title="Categories"
                      icon={TabIcon}
                      hideNavBar={true}
                      component={Categories}/>
                  <Scene
                      key="search"
                      title="Search"
                      icon={TabIcon}
                      hideNavBar={true}
                      component={Search}/>
                  <Scene
                      key="profile"
                      title="Profile"
                      icon={TabIcon}
                      hideNavBar={true}
                      component={Profile}/>
              </Scene>

        </Scene>
    </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

and then create your `TabIcon` function:

```
const TabIcon = ({ focused, title }) => {
  switch (title) {
    case "Home":
      color = focused ? 'black' : 'grey';
      return (
        <View style={styles.tabView}>
          <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} color={color} />
          <Text style={styles.tabLabel}>Home</Text>
        </View>
      );
    case "Categories":
      color = focused ? 'black' : 'grey';
      return (
        <View style={styles.tabView}>
          <Icon name="ios-list" size={30} color={color} />
          <Text style={styles.tabLabel}>Categories</Text>
        </View>
      );
    case "Search":
      color = focused ? 'black' : 'grey';
      return (
        <View style={styles.tabView}>
          <Icon name="ios-search" size={30} color={color} />
          <Text style={styles.tabLabel}>Search</Text>
        </View>
      );
    case "Profile":
      color = focused ? 'black' : 'grey';
      return (
        <View style={styles.tabView}>
          <Icon name="md-person" size={30} color={color} />
          <Text style={styles.tabLabel}>Profile</Text>
        </View>
      );
  }

};
```

at the end you can use own style by create styleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tabBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  navigationBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  navigationBarTitleStyle: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  icon: {
    width: 18,
    height: 22,
    padding: 5
  },
  tabView: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  tabLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tabbaricon` and `tabBarLabel`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaricon

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


return (
<Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, horizontal, tintColor}) => (
            //  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaricon
            <Image
              fadeDuration={0}
              style={{width: 22, height: 22}}
              source={}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
</Tab.Navigator>
)
```

Comment: <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#f0edf6"
        inactiveColor="#3e2465"
        barStyle={{
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor:'orange',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
            borderTopRightRadius: 25,
            borderBottomEndRadius: 25,
            borderBottomLeftRadius:25,
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            margin: 20
        }}>